# Conditions for template specialization type?

Tags: c++

I've made a specialized template base on original template class like this:

**Base template:**

```
template <typename T>
class MyData {
public:
    MyData(T param) : data(param) {}

    T GetData() const {
        return data;
    }

private:
    T data;
};
```

Specialized template:

```
template <>
class MyData<char*> {
public:
    MyData(const char* param) {
        int len = static_cast<int>(strlen(param));
        data = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy_s(data, static_cast<rsize_t>(len + 1), param);
    }

    ~MyData() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    const char* GetData() const {
        return data;
    }

private:
    char* data;
};
```

This code works well, but I'm wondering if there any explicit conditions for the type of template specialization. For example, if I make function specialization, return type and all parameters' type must be the same.

```
template <>
const char* Add(const char* pLeft, const char* pRight) {
-----------     -----------        -----------
     |                |                  |
     +----------------+------------------+
    ...
}
```

In class `MyData`, template type of class is `char*` but the parameter type of constructor is `const char*`. However, there is no error while compiling the code. So I want to know is there any type conditions like this in class template specialization.

Comment: Thee number of types in the specialization must match the number of types in the original unspecialized template.   Other than that I can't tell what you're asking.  Different template types aren't related, so there are no requirements on them... they are completely unrelated types that are just selected based on the provided type.

Comment: And that's not true about a function specialization - it's true in that specific case, but not if a parameter is a templated type.  Template specialization selection is done at compile time, so they don't need to be exactly the same because their calls can be known ahead of time and set up differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference here between function specializations and class specializations. Class specializations may be completely different types with another set of members, functions and base classes. The following compiles well:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar() {}

private:
    int val;
};

class Parent {};

template <>
class Foo<char> : public Parent
{
public:
    void BarBar() {}

private:
    double val;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    Foo<char> ff;
}
```